# Lines after the executeQuery(quer) not executing?

Tags: java, sql, try-catch, executequery

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   String del_user = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter the Username To be deleted     :"  ,"Delete User !", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

   try {    
      stmt = con.createStatement(); 
      String quer = "delete from Udet where username='"+del_user+"'";
      rs=stmt.executeQuery(quer);

      int count=0; 
      while(rs.next())
      {
         count++;
     }

     if(count==1)
     {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The user has been deleted");
     }

     else
     {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No such User Exists");
     }

  } catch(Exception e){}


}
```

THE QUERY EXECUTES FINE ! THE RECORD GETS DELETED BUT THE LINES AFTER QUERYEXECUTION ARE NOT EXECUTING ...
the JOptionPane will work after the try block but then the value of count wont be determined...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `DELETE` statement doesn't return a `ResultSet` and therefore you should use the method `stmt.executeUpdate(quer);` instead of `stmt.executeQuery(quer);`.
One way you can see how many results were deleted from the query is run a `SELECT COUNT(*)` query on the table before and after the `DELETE` using the `executeQuery()` method which will both times return a `ResultSet` with a single result containing how many records the table contains. After running it before and after the `DELETE` you can compare the 2 numbers. 
The result will probably be a `String` but you can just use `int integer = Integer.parseInt(String);` to get the `int` from it. The code should look like this:

```
stmt = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count FROM table_name";
int initialSize = 0;
rs = stmt.executeQuery(stmt);
while(rs.next){
  initialSize = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("Count");
}
```

Run the `DELETE` query and then repeat the `COUNT` query passing the `int` into a new variable (for this answer I'll call it `newSize`) so the number of changes the `DELETE` made would be:

```
int changesMade = initialSize - newSize;
```